# Is there any way to make several big methods calls in parallel within one method? While trying to use, thread my dev server hangs up

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

```
def call
  a_call
  b_call
  c_call
end

def a_call
  does_something
end

def b_call
  does_something
end

def c_call
  does_something
end
```

Call all these methods at once so that response time is less.

Tried it using Thread dev server but it hangs up. Concurrent-ruby is not descriptive enough to use.

Comment: Did you try just wrapping each call in `Thread.new`?

Comment: yeah, added Thread.new in all calls and used join. Server got hanged up

Comment: Why do you need to join the threads?

Comment: What should I do then? I need to add response from multiple calls

Comment: You might have to warp your code in `Rails.application.executor.wrap { ... }`, see [Threading and Code Execution in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html)